# How do I fill arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I know how to do it normally, but I could swear that you could fill out out like a[0] = {0,0,0,0}; How do you do it that way? I did try Google, but I didn't get anything helpful.

Comment: The real question you should be asking is how to make this work: a[0] = someFunction(4, 0);.  For that reason, the selected "correct" answer is not useful.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can also do it as part of the declaration:

```
int[] a = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Comment: int[] a = new int[4] would accomplish the same thing, since 0 is the default value.

Comment: Or int[] a = {0, 0, 0, 0}; . You only need the new int[] if the constant is not immediately used in a declaration.

Comment: this is not usefull when you have a big array. @cdmckay's answer is better.

Comment: Don't forget the age-old programming rule: "If you find yourself copying/pasting code, you're doing something wrong."  The number of zero's, or whatever default value, is just being copied and pasted here.

Answer (score 284):

Check out the [Arrays.fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28boolean%5B%5D,%20boolean%29) methods.

```
int[] array = new int[4];
Arrays.fill(array, 1); // [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: +1 because I didn't know about Arrays.fill() method. I always did it with a for loop. :D

Comment: @GrantGalitz I'm actually not convinced about that, do you have a link to an article or smt? Because unlike the `System` classes, `java.util.Arrays` is a class implemented by Java, and looking through the source shows that it is **no different** from a normal loop.

Comment: Arrays of ints are initialized with 0, so the second line isn't necessary in the above example.

Comment: @PatrickBrinich-Langlois: It still might be worthwhile in order to indicate your intent that it be zeroed.

Answer (score 17):

[`Arrays.fill()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(long%5b%5d,%20long)). The method is overloaded for different data types, and there is even a variation that fills only a specified range of indices.

Answer (score 17):

In Java-8 you can use `IntStream` to produce a stream of numbers that you want to repeat, and then convert it to array. This approach produces an expression suitable for use in an initializer:

```
int[] data = IntStream.generate(() -> value).limit(size).toArray();
```

Above, `size` and `value` are expressions that produce the number of items that you want tot repeat and the value being repeated.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/gPEE7p)

Answer (score 10):

```
Arrays.fill(arrayName,value);
```

in java

```
int arrnum[] ={5,6,9,2,10};
for(int i=0;i<arrnum.length;i++){
  System.out.println(arrnum[i]+" ");
}
Arrays.fill(arrnum,0);
for(int i=0;i<arrnum.length;i++){
  System.out.println(arrnum[i]+" ");
}
```

Output

```
5 6 9 2 10
0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 6):

An array can be initialized by using the `new Object {}` syntax.

For example, an array of `String` can be declared by either:

```
String[] s = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};
String[] s2 = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
```

Primitives can also be similarly initialized either by:

```
int[] i = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
int[] i2 = {1, 2, 3};
```

Or an array of some `Object`:

```
Point[] p = new Point[] {new Point(1, 1), new Point(2, 2)};
```

All the details about arrays in Java is written out in [Chapter 10: Arrays](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html) in [The Java Language Specifications, Third Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

Array elements in Java are initialized to default values when created. For numbers this means they are initialized to 0, for references they are null and for booleans they are false.

To fill the array with something else you can use  [Arrays.fill()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(int[],%20int)) or as part of the declaration

```
int[] a = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0};
```

There are no shortcuts in Java to fill arrays with arithmetic series as in some scripting languages.

Comment: I don't know but for float eclipse say that this is correct...WHY?: `float[] ave = new float[] {(float) 1.2, (float) 4.3, (float) 10.2}`

Answer (score -3):

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! This answer would be improved if you could add some explanation for it, rather than just plopping some code down. Why would this be preferable to any of the other answers already provided on this 7 year old question?