# Is there any way of creating an array filled with a particular value in java?

Tags: java, arrays

My question is that, is there any way of creating a new array(any datatype) filled with a particular value as we can do in C/C++?
eg :- int array[100] = {0};

I know, we can first create an array and then fill it with any value using java.util.Arrays, but I was asking if there was a single statement to do it like in C/C++

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576855/how-do-i-fill-arrays-in-java

Comment: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=fill+array+with+default+values+java May the power of google be with you

Comment: If you're just initializing to zero, you don't have to do anything special: just `int[] array = new int[100]`.

Comment: I think this actually deserves an answer and less downvoting. Note that the question is *not* how to fill an existing array, but how to create and initialize a new array in a compact way. A statically declared array of zeroes of length greater than about 10 is braindead, and `int [] array = new int[100]; Array.fill(array, 100);` is so Java 7. It can be expressed readably in a single statement in Java 8, like this: `int[] a = IntStream.generate(() -> 0).limit(100).toArray();`