# How to create Funtion to update variables that differ i?

Tags: java, anylogic

I have several variables that differ "i", e.g. wip0, wip1,... wip26. Each one is a collection of integers. This is probably very easy but I can't find the answer.

How can I create a function to update a given variable?

I have a function to update a specific variable, but I don't want to create 27 functions.

Now I have:

```
updateWip(int type, int quantity){
int temp;
temp = wip.get(type);
temp = temp + quantity;
wip.set(materialType, temp);
}
```

I will need something like this:

```
updateWip(int type, int quantity, int station)
```

Comment: Make a local array to store the `27` variables, and store it there?

Comment: Don't have many variables like this.  Have an array in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an array in your surrounding class and make use of the `station` argument as the array index, like the following:

```
class Stations {
  WIP[] wip = new WIP[27];
  public void updateWip(int type, int quantity, int station) {
     //...
     wip[station].set(materialType, temp);
  }
}
```

However, this requires you to initialize the array fields, because each field like ´wip[0]´ will be `null` in the first place. To overcome this, you can add a loop initializing the array fields e.g. in the constructor. For more information about arrays take a look at [this site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

When you are using java8 you can also use the streaming API to create a filled array with the desired content. Then you could declare the property in the class like this:

```
WIP[] wip = IntStream.generate(() -> new WIP()).limit(27).toArray();
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31078246/3165552), where i got the streaming template from.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create a function to update a given variable?

You don't.  The correct solution is to replace `wip0, wip1,... wip26`  with a single variable which is an array with 27 elements.  Then use array indexing to select the appropriate array element to read / update.

In theory, you could use reflection to update the variables if they were fields (not local variables!), but that is pretty horrible (complicated code, orders of magnitude inefficient, fragile).  Just don't do it ...