# Filling 1D Array without for loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a task of filling an array using a sentinel controlled while loop (I have to use JOptionPane).

```
    int score[] = new int [10];
int x = 0;
int size = 0;
x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the score"));

while ( x != -1){
score[size]= x ;
x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the score"));
size++;    

}
System.out.println(score[0]+score[1]+score[2]+score[3]+score[4]);


}
```

This is my current code, the result from println is 15 if I input : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1.
Could you please help me finding what have I done? I am a new java user.

Comment: use array.length with for loop

Comment: You should look here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576855/how-do-i-fill-arrays-in-java

Comment: @Redwan I have seen this question yet I have not found answer in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can only handle a fixed number of scores, which is 5. It will give you nonsense for less than 5 scores and wrong answer for 6 to 10 scores, and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for more than 10 scores. Because you are using a fixed-length array of 10 elements, and manually summing the first 5 elements. You are better off using a dynamic list for storing the user input and use a for-loop to handle the summation.

Apart from this major issue, the code that handles user input is repeated twice, and it doesn't handle non-integer strings. You should put that code in a method and give it a proper name.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Filling1DArray {

    /**
     * Ask the user to enter an integer
     * @return The integer the user entered or -1 if the input is not an integer
     */
    private static int nextScore() {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the score (or -1 to stop)"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        // Dynamic list to hold the user input
        List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>();

        // Get user input until she enters -1 or some non-integer
        int score;
        while ((score = nextScore()) != -1)
            scores.add(score);

        // Compute the sum using stream API
        System.out.println(scores.stream().reduce((a, b)->a+b).orElse(-1));

        // Or a simple ranged-for
        int sum = 0;
        for (int s : scores) sum += s;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int sent=0;
while(sent!=1){
    //append to array
    //do something which may change the value of sent
}
```

Comment: so I should do something like
`double sent=0
 double array[] = new double array[10]
sent = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("...");
while(sent !=1){
 sent += array[];
 sent = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("...");

}`
?

Comment: Not really, I think it might be a much simpler concept than you realize. Think of the sentinel variable as a flag whose only purpose is to let the loop know when to terminate. e.g. if (the array holds all the values I want) {sent=1} therefore the 'while' condition will no longer be met.