# How to create an int[] with fixed length and specific number with java stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I know how to get an `int[]` with a range of numbers:

```
int[] array = IntStream.of(0, 3).toArray();
```

But how can I get it with fixed length and one specific number?

Comment: btw there is also a java-stream solution provided in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
IntStream.generate(() -> x).limit(y)
```

is what you need. Replace `x` and `y` with any number you like and you will produce a stream that has `y` lots of the number `x`.

You can obviously then call `toArray` or do whatever operation you want.

[`IntStream.generate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#generate-java.util.function.IntSupplier-) creates an infinite stream using the supplier.

Comment: [or simpler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52677950/1059372)

Comment: @Eugene in what way?

Comment: @Aomine an infinite stream with a `limit` (that does not introduce the `SIZED` flag) over that simpler call *just* to generate an array?

Comment: @Eugene IMHO I wouldn't even look into that at this stage unless otherwise, one notices a performance bottleneck. this approach is more compact and readable.

Comment: @Aomine may be to you more readable, not me.

Comment: @Eugene and the other people who have upvoted the answer as well as the person who has accepted the answer. `IntStream.generate(() -> x).limit(y)` reads as "generate me `x`; `y` number of times", `int[] arr = new int[10];
Arrays.setAll(arr, x -> 1);` reads as "initialise an int array with 10 slots, then set all the elements of the specified array, using the provided generator function" but alright completely understandable that not everyone will agree with a given solution :).

Comment: @Aomine not only a solution, but us, disagreeing here, is actually a good thing ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
int[] array = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n).map(x -> m).toArray();
```

should produce an array of length `n` filled with `m`.

The following Q&A has other answers that use other approaches, such as the `Arrays.fill` method.

- [How do I fill arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576855/how-do-i-fill-arrays-in-java)

Comment: This works well if you want the value to be a function of the index. I use `IntStream.range(0, n)` which is shorter. ;) +1

Comment: @PeterLawrey [or even simpler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52677950/1059372)

Answer (score 3):

Or simpler again.

```
// n elements of value m
int[]a=new int[n];
Arrays.fill(a,m);
```

Comment: which internally is nothing more than a loop...

Comment: @Eugene which of the answers is not a loop, internally? Besides that, if I had to bet on which version gets optimized best by the JVM, i.e. has a chance of getting the initial zero-filling eliminated and the fastest memory fill operation, I’d bet on this one.

Comment: @Holger I absolutely honestly thought about this zero filling and even thought that in this case (or may be others too), there's not need for that to happen, but once you declare an array, it will always be prefilled with zeros and I don't think that the VM can eliminate that, at least I have no idea how to prove that

Comment: @Eugene as elaborated in [this blog](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/), the JVM is capable of eliminating zeroing when the array creation is immediately followed by an overwriting copying operation. I’d expect an immediate subsequent `fill` operation to get a similar treatment. All other versions seen here require inlining several other code, to be able to determine whether the result will truly overwrite the entire array without reading any field and can not fail in the middle.

Comment: @Holger beautiful! thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Or even simpler with an API that was written for that:

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
Arrays.setAll(arr, x -> 1);

// or if you have enough data for parallel to make any difference
Arrays.parallelSetAll(arr, x -> 1);
```

Comment: Or even https://stackoverflow.com/a/52677996/57695

Comment: @PeterLawrey I wanted to edit just for that, but too late I guess

Comment: Yours is better is you don't want all the elements the same.