# How can i fill one cell of array in java (android Studio)

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop, debugging

I write this but **all cells fill together.**

how can I fix it.

```
 Integer [] history=new Integer[5];

 for (int i=0;i<history.length;i++) {
     history[i]=Jamkon.intValue();
 }

 txt_H.setText(Arrays.toString(history));
```

Comment: After you write `txt_H.setText(Arrays.toString(history));` what is the output and what do you want to get as your correct output?

Comment: check this out: [array fill method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/576859/8399393)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a loop which will go through all indices of the array.  If you want to only write one value, you will have to decide on what `index` first.

```
    int index =??? 
    history[index] = Jamkon.intValue()
```

Comment: i want print first cell next time i click on button print last cell and next cell until all cells fill.

Comment: You need to save that index somewhere and read/write to it every time the user clicks. Please show more of your code.

Comment: i fix it tnx sir.

Comment: Please, check my answer as solving the issue or rather, post your own solution as the correct answer for others to look at in the future!